# Command line parameters for an inline python script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a set of comman-line tools that I implement as bash functions, eg:

```
function sf
{
    sftp $(svr $1)
}
```

where `svr` is another function that translates a short name to a fully qualified domain name. I got the idea that I wanted to convert this function:

```
function irpt
{
    ~/tools/icinga_report $*
}
```

to something like:

```
function irpt
{
python <<!
import requests
...lots of python stuff...
!
}
```

This works perfectly, except for one thing: I need to add the parameters somewhere, but I can't see where. I have tried to enclose the whole python block in `{ }`, but it doesn't work:

```
function irpt
{
python <<!
import requests
...lots of python stuff...
!
}
```

The shell doesn't accept the definition:

```
-bash: /etc/profile: line 152: syntax error near unexpected token `$*'
-bash: /etc/profile: line 152: `} $*'
```

Is there any way to implement this?
===EDIT===
Inspired by the answer I accepted, this is what I did, maybe it is useful for others:

```
function irpt
{
python <<!
import requests

param="$*".split(' ')

...lots of python stuff...
!
}
```

This works beautifully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
function irpt
{
python <<!
import requests
v1='$1'
print(v1)
!
}
```

Running the function:

```
$ irpt hello
hello
$
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little weird, but you can use the bash `<(command)` syntax to provide a script file dynamically (in reality, a named pipe); the rest follows.

```
function demo {
    python <(echo 'import sys; print(sys.argv)') "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
foo() {
cmd=$(cat <<EOF
print("$1")
EOF
)
python -c "$cmd"
}
```

Alternatively,

```
foo() {
python -c $(cat <<EOF
print("$1")
EOF
)
}
```

And then use the function like

```
foo test
```